# Import raster to R - values appear as NAs?

Tags: r, raster, na

Why does R display NA for the values of an imported raster?

```
#load libraries
library(raster)

#set working directory
setwd("C:/Users/Documents/myData")

#import raster data 
r <- raster("myRasterdata.tif")
```

Returns: 
    class: RasterLayer

```
dimensions: 34073, 19663, 669977399  (nrow, ncol, ncell)

resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)

extent : -969193.5, -379303.5, 277627.9, 1299818  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

coord. ref. : +proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-95 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 

data source : C:/Users/Documents/myData/myRasterdata.tif 

names       : dem

values      : 0, 1857  (min, max)
```

As you can see, it imports the file fine, and shows that there are values ranging from 0 to 1857, but when I use the function head(r), I get all NA values returned.

Likewise when I import many rasters and build a stack, and likewise when I try to readGDAL function.

So when I try to do an "extract" function with a polygon layer, I get all NA values returned.

Comment: And when you plot? Do you see your data correctly? Head will give you the first few lines of data (top left corner of the raster) which may be NA. Try `hist(r[])`.

Comment: Thanks, i tried your suggestion and it appears to plot some data so I guess there is data afterall! (note, i also tried "tail" which also gives all NA values, I guess for the same reason). But how then do I get rid of the NA values? I tried na.omit which doesn't work. And why isn't it giving me values for my extract function, even though I specificy na.rm = TRUE?

Comment: Is your polygon overlapping non-missing data? Is your polygon the same projection?

Comment: @Pascal I think user has a raster that has NAs dispersed around the canvas. Try `head(x[], 200)` and see if you get some data. This is just a displaying problem. When you call head, it starts printing from the top left corner. Without data, we can just guess. I would suggest you add data to your question (minimally reproducible example).

Comment: What is the purpose of "getting rid of NA values"?

Comment: Thank you both of you for your comments. The purpose of getting rid of the NA values was to ensure my follow-up analyses (extract means from polygon) were not using these data, as my initial extract results returned all NA values. However, I think it was a projection issue afterall! I re-projected the polygon layer to ensure it matched the raster, it seems to be working now! What a silly mistake on my behalf. Thanks again!!

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this naive question, but I still struggle to find a good way... What does the `length` of the list returned by `raster::extract(ras, vec)` tell me? I'm a little confused about that

Comment: one thing I found superuseful is the `velox`-package. It does raster-extraction superfast!!;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trim function to remove NA values.

```
r<-trim(r)
```