# Importing raster stack returns large NA values

Tags: r, extract, raster, na

I imported raster stacks after loading the required packages. On calling head() and summary() I find that R is somehow reading the raster as NA on import. When I run hist() I am able to see the spread of pixel values, hence, data is definitely there. I have checked other support links:  [NAs returned when extracting values from a raster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973986/nas-returned-when-extracting-values-from-a-raster),
[Import raster to R - values appear as NAs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662920/import-raster-to-r-values-appear-as-nas). But I am not able to understand what is going wrong.

```
library(raster)
x <- brick("raster.tiff")
x
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 1610, 2640, 4440744, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 30, 30  (x, y)
#extent     : 694781.4, 773171.4, 1261280, 1311920  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=utm +zone=43 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0 
#source     : file-path.grd 
#names      :        x.1,        x.2,          x.3,          x.4 
#min values :     275.2141,     357.1080,     370.5995,     592.5593 
#max values :     2122.801,     5525.976,     6406.745,     6870.159 

x[1]
#                x.1        x.2         x.3            x.4
#[1,]           NA           NA           NA           NA

summary(x)
#               x.1        x.2           x.3         x.4
#Min.        305.2251     425.7844     401.7832     641.0283
#1st Qu.     565.8536     796.9203     887.6340    1941.3184
#Median      652.2755     918.4586    1071.1154    2192.9951
#3rd Qu.     758.0400    1100.3450    1380.2045    2464.9850
#Max.       1287.9128    2654.8047    3272.8123    4073.0056
#NA's    1433504.0000 1433504.0000 1433504.0000 1433504.0000
```

Also, I am new to R and even stackoverflow so maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Maybe the NA correspond to masked values? You could use `plot(x)` to see if the image corresponds to the raster you are expecting.

Comment: In principle there is nothing wrong with having many `NA`s. Perhaps these represent the ocean?

Comment: @JonathanV.Solórzano: Thanks. The NA's do correspond to the masked values. I think I just fretted over nothing thinking that I had no data or done something wrong somehow. Running plot did return a graph showing the distribution of the values. Also, when I converted the raster into dataframe and omitted NA values (na.omit(x1)) I could clearly see the data.

Comment: @RobertHijmans: Thanks. I understand the meaning of the NAs now. They don't represent the ocean here though, but just the empty space outside the clipped region of interest.